# Xamarin Stacklayout VerticalOptions CenterAndExpand not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi Guys probably very easy question for Xamarin expert I am trying to vertically center align stacklayout control and it is working fine in android mobile but not working in windows mobile device. My code is below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="aa.Views.MainPage">
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  Padding="20" Spacing="10">
      <Entry x:Name="enEmail" Placeholder="Email"></Entry>
      <Entry x:Name="enPassword" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Password"></Entry>
      <Button Text="Login" Clicked="OnClicked_btnLogin" x:Name="btnLogin"></Button>
      <Button Text="Register" Clicked="OnClicked_btnRegister" x:Name="btnRegister"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

For more details please have a look at the attached images and help me how would i align it in center of screen for windows phone

[image]

Comment: Is this the only code you have on your page?@AtulChaudhary

Comment: The problem is the scroll view. Remove and try.@AtulChaudhary

Comment: removing it worked but then when i click on textbox it doesn't scroll and my keyboard hides the control and that is why I got the scrillview

Comment: Posted my answer below@AtulChaudhary

Answer (score 1):

its `StackLayout`: puts views consecutive one another. If you want to move buttons to down side use `Grid` instead like:

```
  <Grid RowSpacing="10"><!--RowSpacing gives some space between rows-->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!--You can also use constant size also-->
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <!--This fill the empty space-->
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Entry Grid.Row="0" Placeholder=" Email"/>
    <Entry Grid.Row="1" Placeholder=" Password" IsPassword="True"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="3" Text="Login" />
    <Button Grid.Row="4" Text="Register" />

  </Grid>
```

Comment: up voting you for your effort but I am still looking for an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, it will give you a scroll view plus your fields will be aligned to the center

```
<ScrollView>
      <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="maincontent" Spacing="0">
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  Padding="20" Spacing="10">
            <Entry x:Name="enEmail" Placeholder="Email"></Entry>
            <Entry x:Name="enPassword" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Password"></Entry>
            <Button Text="Login" Clicked="OnClicked_btnLogin" x:Name="btnLogin"></Button>
            <Button Text="Register" Clicked="OnClicked_btnRegister" x:Name="btnRegister"></Button>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview is not working with this syntax though i like the idea

Comment: It will work if your screen runs out of space.@AtulChaudhary

Comment: it is running out of space when clicking on entry control and then when I want to scroll

Comment: up voting you for your effort but I am still looking for an answer

Comment: Try adding FillAndExpand to scroll view.https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21565/scrollview-inside-stacklayout-not-visible @AtulChaudhary

Comment: As I suspected it puts the control in the center but in windows 8 mobile emulator it doesn't scroll